# What's the simplest configuration to assign www.domain.com and domain.com to the same location

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain

I've assigned a virtual host for the domain www.website.com on my hosting.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/mywebsite
    ServerName www.website.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I've just realized that "`website.com`" is not forwarded to the correct path. Should I add a new virtualhost for it ? Or add a new ServerName parameter ? (it's the same path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias).

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to make sure that in your DNS configuration you point to the right server address because if i am not misunderstanding from your case, that you actually can create point different machine for 
1. website.com - f.e point to 192.168.1.1
2. www.website.com - f.e point to 192.168.1.2